# How can I use <a tag > php?

Tags: php, html

```
<?php if isset($_GET[‘id’])) { ?>
<a href =“”>hello</a>
<?php} ?>
```

Any reason  for using php twice?

Why can’t I use like this?

```
<?php if isset($_GET[‘id’])) { 
<a href =“”>hello</a>
} ?>
```

Pls somebody explain me T.T

Comment: Do note the quotes your using are not valid HTML. Just use `"`

Comment: ALso be careful, you have non Ascii quotes in that code. That will cause you issues somewhere down the line. Single quote = `'` and not `‘` and double quote = `"` and not `“`

Answer (score 5):

Code **inside** `<?php` and `?>` is executed by the PHP engine.

Content **outside** that is sent directly to the output stream (in this case to the browser).

`<a href =“”>hello</a>` is HTML that needs to be sent to the browser. It isn't PHP and trying to treat it as PHP will throw an exception.

Comment: Well you could suggest using an `echo`

Comment: @DarkBee — I don't recommend using `echo` in this situation. It rapidly leads to escape sequence hell as soon as the content gets any more complex.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the HTML tag inside the PHP opening and closing tags and have it interpreted by the PHP engine if you ECHO it to the browser:

```
<?php 

if isset($_GET[‘id’])) { 

 echo "<a href =''>hello</a>";

} 

 ?>
```

In this way the HTML is just a string that is passed to the browser by the PHP engine interpreting the inbuilt PHP ECHO command and then received, interpreted and rendered by the browser. This makes everything PHP so you can enclose the whole script in a single set of tags.